# MYSQL Slow store INSERT

Tags: mysql, performance, loops, insert

Im migrating a MSSQL DB to a MySQL. And I have a SP that makes many insert in a table, Its work fine y mssql but the same procedure in Mysql is taking too much time. I read that to make many insert is something that not performe faster.

Its a while loops that make an insert in every cycle.

I would like to know if you have a faster way to do it?

When I do it in python for instance, I add ever select into a list, and at the end of the loop i make just one insert of all rows. I trying to figure it out how to do this in a mysql SP.

This is the SP, but I can not put all tables I call here.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_indisp_cscs3`()
BEGIN
                                                            /*BORRA LA INFORMACION A SER REPROCESADA*/
    DELETE FROM indisp;
    /*WHERE mes = MONTH(CURDATE())
    AND año = YEAR(CURDATE());*/
                                                        /*Comienza la fiesta, se armó la culiandanga*/
                                                        
    SET @row  = (SELECT min(cscsID) from cscs where month(inicio) = month(curdate()) AND YEAR(inicio) = YEAR(curdate()));
    WHILE  @row <= (SELECT max(cscsID) from cscs ) DO
        SET @inicio = (SELECT inicio FROM cscs WHERE cscsid = @row); 
        SET @fin = (select   fin from cscs where cscsid = @row); 
        SET @hourini = @inicio;
        SET @compID = (select compID from cscs where cscsid = @row);
        SET @vencomp = (select ven_comp from cscs where cscsid = @row);
        SET @venserv = (select ven_serv from cscs where cscsid = @row);
            
        WHILE @inicio < @fin AND  MONTH(@inicio) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(@inicio) = YEAR(CURDATE()) DO
            
            INSERT INTO indisp (ticketid)/*, diasem, splitdate, año,mes, hour,affected, compID, serv_pais_prodID, ven_comp,ven_serv)*/
            VALUES (
                    (select ticketid from cscs where cscsid = @row)/*,
                    DAYOFWEEK(@inicio),
                    @inicio,
                    year(@inicio),
                    month(@inicio),
                    @hourini,
                    1,
                    @compID,
                    (select serv_pais_prodID from cscs where cscsID = @row),
                    (select CASE
                        WHEN @vencomp = 1 THEN  (select venx  from  ven1  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 2 THEN  (select venx  from  ven2  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 3 THEN  (select venx  from  ven3  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 4 THEN  (select venx  from  ven4  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 5 THEN  (select venx  from  ven5  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 6 THEN  (select venx  from  ven6  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 7 THEN  (select venx  from  ven7  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 8 THEN  (select venx  from  ven8  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 9 THEN  (select venx  from  ven9  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 10 THEN  (select venx  from  ven10  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 11 THEN  (select venx  from  ven11  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 12 THEN  (select venx  from  ven12  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @vencomp = 13 THEN  (select venx  from  ven13  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        ELSE 0
                    END),
                                        (select CASE
                        WHEN @venserv = 1 THEN  (select venx  from  ven1  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 2 THEN  (select venx  from  ven2  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 3 THEN  (select venx  from  ven3  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 4 THEN  (select venx  from  ven4  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 5 THEN  (select venx  from  ven5  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 6 THEN  (select venx  from  ven6  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 7 THEN  (select venx  from  ven7  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 8 THEN  (select venx  from  ven8  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 9 THEN  (select venx  from  ven9  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 10 THEN  (select venx  from  ven10  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 11 THEN  (select venx  from  ven11  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 12 THEN  (select venx  from  ven12  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        WHEN @venserv = 13 THEN  (select venx  from  ven13  WHERE hour = DATE_FORMAT(@inicio,'%H:%i:%s') and diasem = DAYOFWEEK(@inicio))
                        ELSE 0
                    END)  */               
                    );
    
                    
            SET @inicio =  @inicio + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;
        END WHILE;
        
        SET @row = @row +1;
    END WHILE;
    UPDATE indisp
    SET ven_serv = 0
    WHERE ven_serv IS NULL;
   
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Build yourself a table of dates.  Then `LEFT JOIN` that table to your other data.

The one-time setup of the table of dates would involve a loop (or cross-join or table of integers or MariaDB seq table).

Then the `JOIN` would be quite efficient; possibly more efficient than what you had in MSSql.  There would be no loop, just a `JOIN`.  It would probably be a `LEFT JOIN` if you need to create rows even for holidays, etc.